# File IO duplicate checking more efficient?

Tags: c#, file, io, mp3, parallel-processing

Basically I have this application which scans through all mp3's in a folder and returns a list of files without duplicates. I have two methods to perform this task. The first removed duplicate file names and the second removes duplicate files with matching mp3 IDv3 tags.

However my folder has about 5000 files which it successfully removes duplicates to like 4900, but it takes forever! Can anyone suggest a more efficient method? I've used parallelism to make things as fast as possible but it's still dog slow.

First method to remove duplicate file names:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetFilesFromDir(string dir)
        {
            return Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Distinct();
        }
```

The second method goes through each file returned from the above method and checks it's IDv3 tag (Artist - Song Title) information to ensure that duplicate songs are not present.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> RemoveDuplicates(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    var dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    Parallel.ForEach(files, f =>
                                {
                                    string tag = SongInformation.ArtistTitleAlbumString(f);
                                    dictionary.TryAdd(tag, f);
                                });

    return dictionary.Values;
}
```

The two methods are called as follows:

```
var newFiles = RemoveDuplicates(GetFilesFromDir(Settings.SharedFolder));
```

Comment: Profile your existing solution. If the bottleneck is in for example, the I/O, being clever with this 'outer' code may not be of much help. Also, what is the CPU usage on your machine with the `Parallel.ForEach` version?

Comment: CPU usage is very low (around 1-8%) on a dual core and a quad core machine.

Comment: I don't know why you are doing a Parallel.ForEach. The ConcurrentDictionary is synchronized anyway, so you aren't going to distribute much processing.

Comment: "CPU usage is very low (around 1-8%)" - This is a *strong* sign that this is I/O-bound. Please confirm with a profiler.

Comment: So lets say that is it I/O-bound, there probably is not much I could do to speed it up without a change in hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the call to `Distinct()` seems pointless here. `Directory.GetFiles()` returns full file names (with path) so they are always distinct.

Comment: the ArtistTitleAlbumString needs to be distinct, not the filename/path

Comment: I agree with removing the Distinct() part. Makes sense and not sure why I put it there in the first place.